# RestFB Login successful, but User fields are null except name,id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am working with RestFB to authenticate users with facebook and get user's facebook details to show in their page.

I found this following URL to make facebook login using RestFB, http://www.codehandling.com/2012/11/facebook-login-using-graph-api-and.html

I followed this and successfully get Token, but I am unable to get the User details, such as email, firstName, etc.,

I am getting all those values as null except id and name.

Below is my code,

```
@WebServlet("/callback")
public class CallbackServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static String getAccessTokenFromWebContent (String webContent) {
        String accessToken = null;
        int s = webContent.indexOf("access_token=") + ("access_token=".length());
        int e = webContent.indexOf("&");
        accessToken = webContent.substring(s, e);
        return accessToken;
    }


    private static String getWebContentFromURL(String webnames) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(webnames);
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            //BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
            StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
                builder.append((char) byteRead);
            buffer.close();
            String text=builder.toString();
            return text;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = null;
        String facebookAppId = getServletContext().getInitParameter("facebookAppId");
        String facebookAppSecret = getServletContext().getInitParameter("facebookAppSecret");
        String redirectURL = null;
        String accessURL = null;
        String accessToken = null;
        String webContent = null;

        try {
            StringBuffer redirectURLbuffer = request.getRequestURL();
            int index = redirectURLbuffer.lastIndexOf("/");
            redirectURLbuffer.replace(index, redirectURLbuffer.length(), "").append("/callback");
            redirectURL = URLEncoder.encode(redirectURLbuffer.toString(), "UTF-8");

            code = request.getParameter("code");
            if(null!=code) {
                System.out.println("Code: " + code);
                accessURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + facebookAppId + 
                        "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL + "&client_secret=" + facebookAppSecret + "&code=" + code;
                System.out.println("accessURL: " + accessURL);
                webContent = getWebContentFromURL(accessURL);
                System.out.println("accessURL: " + webContent);
                accessToken = getAccessTokenFromWebContent(webContent);
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error.html");
                return;
            }

            if(null!=accessToken) {
                System.out.println("accessToken: " + accessToken);
                FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
                User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
                System.out.println("User object: " + user.toString()); // here all feilds are null as stated above.
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/welcome.jsp");
            }
            if(null==accessToken)
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error.html");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error.html");
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Console:

```
User object: User[about=null ageRange=null bio=null birthday=null birthdayAsDate=null context=null cover=null currency=null devices=[] education=[] email=null favoriteAthletes=[] favoriteTeams=[] firstName=null gender=null hometown=null hometownName=null id=107027df314 inspirationalPeople=[] installType=null installed=null interestedIn=[] isSharedLogin=null isVerified=null labels=[] languages=[] lastName=null link=null locale=null location=null meetingFor=[] metadata=null middleName=null name=xxxyyy nameFormat=null paymentPricepoints=null picture=null political=null publicKey=null quotes=null relationshipStatus=null religion=null securitySettings=null sharedLoginUpgradeRequiredBy=null significantOther=null sports=[] testGroup=null thirdPartyId=null timezone=null tokenForBusiness=null type=null updatedTime=null username=null verified=null videoUploadLimits=null viewerCanSendGift=null website=null work=[]]
```

### Update

Tried with Norbert's answer, as follows,

```
User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me",User.class,Parameter.with("fields","email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,website,birthday,hometown,location,about,link,locale,relationship_status,interested_in"));
```

Now I am able to get these fields. But still birthday,about,relationship,interested are null values.

If I used the accessToken from graph API exploler it shows fine.

### update2

In access token debugger I paste my generated token value and hit debug button and I am getting following results,

```
App ID  id : app
User ID : userId : user name
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  1478196037 (49 seconds ago)
Expires 1483380037 (in about 2 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  user_friends, email, ads_management, ads_read, public_profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `Parameter.with("fields","<desired fields here>")` to the fetchObject call.

Check the documentation here: http://restfb.com/documentation/#advanced-usage-selecting-fields

Comment: Hi Norbert, yes its working fine. But there is no birthday, about, etc. Pls see my update and help.

Comment: check your access token in the access token debugger. The permissions should be granted to access these fields ...

Comment: Hi Norbert, thanks for your comment. I update my question with debug results as you suggested. Pls look in to that.

Comment: You don't have the permission to get about, birthday and so on. That's the reason why the User object has the fields not filled. You first need to get an access token with the additional permissions.

Comment: This is my authURL, `String authURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="
                + facebookAppId
                + "&redirect_uri="
                + callbackURL
                + "&scope=user_about_me,"
                + "user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,"
                + "user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email";`

Comment: Yes, but the access token debugger output does not reflect this. I think you are using the application as non-developer and it is not reviewed. The  permissions in the access token debugger are all usable without review. You should try this as app admin/developer or let Facebook review it. And I don't think you get all these permissions reviewed!